# No Module Named 'apscheduler'

Tags: python, apscheduler

I can't figure out why apscheduler comes up with 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'`

I have tried uninstalling it, used earlier versions.

I am running python 3.7.4, pip version 19.2.2

version 3.6.1 of apscheduler was installed

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler



if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(Get_Current_Location, 'interval', seconds=10)
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'`

C:\Users\Carl>pip list
Package         Version

---

altgraph        0.16.1
APScheduler     3.6.1
certifi         2019.6.16
chardet         3.0.4
DateTime        4.3
future          0.17.1
idna            2.8
numpy           1.17.0
pandas          0.25.0
pefile          2019.4.18
pip             19.2.2
PyInstaller     3.5
pyodbc          4.0.27
python-dateutil 2.8.0
pytz            2019.2
pywin32-ctypes  0.2.0
requests        2.22.0
setuptools      40.8.0
six             1.12.0
tzlocal         2.0.0
urllib3         1.25.3
zope.interface  4.6.0

Comment: Post the whole error message with full traceback **and** the output of `pip -V`.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you installed in one Python but you run code with second Python. You can check `pip -V` and `python -V` or try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: hi Furas, only only have the one verson of python

Comment: File "C:/Users/Carl/Documents/API Insert in SQL Server v2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'

Comment: C:\Users\Carl>python --version
Python 3.7.4

Comment: how did you  install it?

Comment: I have sorted. The issue was with the module not available in Anaconda, which I am using.

Comment: Installed in the console  - conda install -c conda-forge apscheduler

Answer (score 0):

Installing with **pip3** didn't work.

I downloaded **APScheduler** from **PyPi** and installed it directly, same problem.

I got a hunch, I restarted my laptop, and it worked!

I don't know why, I never have problems installing modules, but it works after restart.
give it a try!